# Insert an array to a specified location in named array

Tags: php, arrays

In the array below, how can I push the new array into the $options array at the specified location?

```
$options = array (
    array( "name" => "My Options",
    "type" => "title"),
    array( "type" => "open"),

    array("name" => "Test",
    "desc" => "Test",
    "id" => $shortname."_theme",
    "type" => "selectTemplate",
    "options" => $mydir ),

//I want the pushed array inserted here.

    array("name" => "Test2",
    "desc" => "Test",
    "id" => "test2",
    "type" => "test",
    "options" => $mydir ),

    array( "type" => "close")
    );

    if(someCondition=="met")
    {
    array_push($options, array( "name" => "test",
        "desc" => "description goes here",
        "id" => "testMet",
        "type" => "checkbox",
        "std" => "true"));
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`array_splice`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).  For your example:

```
if($some_condition == 'met') {
  // splice new option into array at position 3
  array_splice($options, 3, 0, array($new_option));
}
```

**Note**: `array_splice` expects the last parameter to be an array of new elements, so for your example you need to pass an array *containing* the new option's array.

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
array_splice($options, 3, 0, $newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

for insert a new array, not to a spesific location(between $r[4] and $r[5]):

```
$options[]=array ("key" => "val"); //insert new array
$options[]=$v; //insert new variable
```

to insert a new array after spesific variable:

```
function array_push(&$array,$after_element_number,$new_var)
{
  array_splice($array, $after_element_number, 0, $new_var);
}

if(someCondition=="met")
{
array_push($options, 2, array( "name" => "test",
    "desc" => "description goes here",
    "id" => "testMet",
    "type" => "checkbox",
    "std" => "true"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [connec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320278/392725) says, you can use `array_splice`, but without forgetting to wrap your array in another array, like this:

```php
if ('met' === $some_condition)
{
  array_splice($options, 3, 0, array(array(
    'name' => 'test',
    'desc' => 'description goes here',
    'id'   => 'testMet',
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'std'  => 'true'
  )));
}
```

**Edit:** connec has already specified its response.